# Why is subquery join much faster than direct join

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, query-performance

I have 2 tables (pages and comments), around **130 000 rows each.**

I want to list pages without any comments (foreign key is comments.page_id)

If I execute the normal left outer join, it takes an amazing **more than 750 seconds** to run. (130k^2 = 17B). Whereas if I execute the same join, but using subqueries for the tables, it takes just **1 second**.

Server version: 5.6.44-log - MySQL Community Server (GPL):

#### Query 1. Normal join, 750+ seconds

```
SELECT p.id
FROM `pages` AS p
LEFT JOIN  `comments` AS c
    ON p.id = c.page_id
WHERE c.page_id IS NULL
GROUP BY 1
```

### Query 2. Join with first table as subquery, Too much time

```
SELECT p.id
FROM (
    SELECT id FROM `pages`
) AS p
LEFT JOIN  `comments` AS c
    ON p.id = c.page_id
WHERE c.page_id IS NULL
GROUP BY 1
```

### Query 3. Join with second table as subquery, 1.6 seconds

```
SELECT p.id
FROM `pages` AS p
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT * FROM `comments`
) AS c
    ON p.id = c.page_id
WHERE c.page_id IS NULL
GROUP BY 1
```

### Query 4. Join with 2 subqueries, 1 second

```
SELECT p.id
FROM (
    SELECT id FROM `pages`
) AS p
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT * FROM `comments`
) AS c
    ON p.id = c.page_id
WHERE c.page_id IS NULL
GROUP BY 1
```

### Query 5. Join with 2 subqueries, selecting only 1 column, 0.2 seconds

```
SELECT p.id
FROM (
    SELECT id FROM `pages`
) AS p
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT page_id FROM `comments`
) AS c
    ON p.id = c.page_id
WHERE c.page_id IS NULL
GROUP BY 1
```

### Query 6. Too much time

```
SELECT p.id
    FROM `pages` AS p
    WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT page_id FROM `comments`
                        WHERE page_id = p.id );;
```

Now, in MySql version 5.7, **all** of the above queries take **"too much time"** to execute.

In MySql 5.7, query 1 and 4 have same explanation:

```
id  select_type  table    partitions     type    possible_keys  key         key_len  ref    rows        filtered    Extra  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    SIMPLE         p       NULL        index       PRIMARY    PRIMARY      4       NULL    147626      100.00      Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort  
1    SIMPLE         c       NULL        ALL         NULL        NULL        NULL    NULL    147790      10.00       Using where; Not exists; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
```

In MySql 5.6, unfortunately I cannot get the explanation for query 1 right now (taking too much time), but for query 4 is the below:

```
id  select_type table       type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows        Extra   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   PRIMARY     <derived2>  ALL     NULL            NULL        NULL    NULL    147626      Using temporary; Using filesort 
1   PRIMARY     <derived3>  ref     <auto_key0>     <auto_key0>  4      p.id    10          Using where; Not exists    
3   DERIVED     comments    ALL     NULL            NULL        NULL    NULL    147790      NULL   
2   DERIVED     pages       index   NULL            PRIMARY     4       NULL    147626      Using index
```

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `pages` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `identifier` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `reference` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `url` varchar(1000) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `moderate` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'default',
 `is_form_enabled` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `date_modified` datetime NOT NULL,
 `date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=147627 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE `comments` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `page_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `website` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `town` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `state_id` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `country_id` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `rating` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `reply_to` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `comment` text NOT NULL,
 `reply` text NOT NULL,
 `ip_address` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `is_approved` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `notes` text NOT NULL,
 `is_admin` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `is_sent` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `sent_to` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `likes` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `dislikes` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `reports` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `is_sticky` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `is_locked` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `is_verified` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `date_modified` datetime NOT NULL,
 `date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=147879 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

### Questions

1. Why is this happening? What does MySql do under the hood?
2. Does this happen only in MySql, or any other Sql as well?
3. How can I write a fast query to get what I need? (In both v 5.6, 5.7)

Comment: GROUP BY is meaningless in this context.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables, `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for both selects, the size of RAM, the version number of MySQL.

Comment: Without constraints/indexes & statistics, optimization opportunities are few. And you say you declared only a PK on id. PS Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular-formatted base table initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics.

Comment: This question is very MySQL version depending which @RickJames already suggested in his answer.. In [MySQL 5.6](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kYJnpsGr8uodFXsZpTT4tc/1) the optimizer seams to want to index a deliverd table notice `<auto_key0>` in the explain and make two DERIVED tables..   In [MySQL 5.7+](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kYJnpsGr8uodFXsZpTT4tc/1) the optimizer seams to flatten out the subquery approach (remove the subqueries by "pushing" up) notice the SHOW WARNINGS output also notice that those "SQL statements (internal handling rewrite)"  are the same on the first and second query..

Comment: Also stop using MyISAM as storage engine because i think its on it way to be deprecated/removed in MySQL ...  A text in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_internal_tmp_disk_storage_engine) *"
Important

In MySQL 8.0.16 and later, on-disk internal temporary tables always use the InnoDB storage engine; as of MySQL 8.0.16, this variable has been removed and is thus no longer supported.
"* is hinting that in mine opinion

Comment: *"Why is this happening? What does MySql do under the hood? "*  To broad to answer *"Does this happen only in MySql, or any other Sql as well?"* To broad to answer as SQL optimizers in other RDMS are totally different... *"How can I write a fast query to get what I need? (In both v 5.6, 5.7)"*  Most likely you are fine using @RickJames query if you index `comments(page_id)` aswell ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your long-running queries, is that you lack an index on the page_id column of the comments table.  Hence, for each row from the pages table, you need to check all rows of the comments table.  Since you are using LEFT JOIN, this is the only possible join order.  What happens in 5.6, is that when you use a subquery in the FROM clause (aka derived table), MySQL will create an index on the temporary table used for the result of the derived table (auto_key0 in the EXPLAIN output). The reason it is faster when you only select one column, is that the temporary table will be smaller.

In MySQL 5.7, such derived tables will be automatically merge into the main query, if possible.  This is done to avoid the extra temporary tables. However, this means that you no longer have an index to use for the join.  (See [this blog post](https://mysqlserverteam.com/derived-tables-in-mysql-5-7/) for details.)

You have two options to improve the query time in 5.7:

1. You can create an index on comments(page_id)
2. You can prevent the subquery from being merged by rewriting it to a query that can not be merged.  Subqueries with aggregation, LIMIT, or UNION will not be merged (see [the blog post](https://mysqlserverteam.com/derived-tables-in-mysql-5-7/) for details). One way to do this is to add a LIMIT clause to the subquery.  In order not to remove any rows from the result, the limit must be larger than the number of rows in the table.

In MySQL 8.0, you can also use an optimizer hint to avoid the merging.  In your case, that would be something like

```
SELECT /*+ NO_MERGE(c) */ ... FROM
```

See slides 34-37 of [this presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/oysteing/using-optimizer-hints-to-improve-mysql-query-performance]) for examples of how to use such hints.

Comment: Do the optimizations apply to MyISAM, too?

Comment: Yes, I do not think any of this depends on the storage engine.

Answer (score 2):

Query 1 has the "explode-implode" syndrome.  First it does a `JOIN`; this explodes the number of rows.  Then it does a `GROUP BY` to shrink back.

Also

The number of comments per page, etc, will have an effect on your query.

`SELECT *` fetches all the columns, when it needs only to know if the `LEFT JOIN` succeeded.  (You observed that.)  Furthermore, you keep none of the columns since you are looking for *missing* rows.

Query 2 should not be as fast as what you found -- It needs to build two temp tables (the "derived" tables), index one of them, then perform the outer query.  (Possibly a new enough version of MySQL can short-circuit some of that effort; old version were notorious at doing an inefficient job.)

Query 3:

Try

```
SELECT p.id
    FROM `pages` AS p
    WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM `comments`
                        WHERE page_id = p.id );
```

ALSO:

- Use InnoDB, not MyISAM.
- `comments` needs `INDEX(page_id)`

Comment: For the NOT EXISTS query to be efficient, I think you will need the anti-join support from MySQL 8.0.17.  Otherwise, it will suffer from the lack of index on comments(page_id).